# SQL Trying to Outer Join Tables but not working

Tags: sql, join

So, I've a Uni assignment and the lecturer has picked this week to be ill and unable to answer questions.

We've been given a baseball database made up of 4 tables to work with. Table structures are as follows:

> TABLENAME:(column1, column2...etc) PK = Primary Key, FK = Foreign Key
>
> PLAYER:(num PK, name, dob, team FK, position)
>
> GAME:(num PK, gamedate, hometeam FK, awayteam FK, homescore,
>   awayscore)
>
> GAMESTAT:(gamenum PK, playernum FK, homeruns, strikeout)
>
> TEAM:(code PK, name, town, ground)

The aim of this particularly question is to obtain the name of the stadium's (ground in team table), the sum of the home runs scored on that ground, the sum of the strikeouts and then the sum of these two values within a specified date range.

My query and issue are below:

```
SELECT 
   t.ground AS GROUNDPLAYED, 
   SUM(gs.homeruns) as TOTALHOMERUNS, 
   SUM(gs.strikeouts) AS TOTALSTRIKEOUTS, 
   SUM(gs.homeruns + gs.strikeouts) AS COMBINEDTOTAL
  FROM team t 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN game g ON g.hometeam = t.code 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN gamestat gs ON g.num = gs.gamenum
 WHERE g.gamedate BETWEEN '7-AUG-2014' AND '13-AUG-2014'
 GROUP BY t.ground;
```

My problem lies in the fact that I get the correct values for games played but regardless of using the LEFT OUTER JOIN, I'm not getting all the stadium's to list. I'm convinced it has to do with the fact that I have had to join to the hometeam from the GAME table and it can only pick the home stadiums based on that.

Any help you may be able to offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: move your WHERE clause to the ON clause for the join to *gamestat*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your WHERE clause to the ON clause for the join to *gamestat*.

By imposing the filter criteria in the WHERE clause, it occurs *after* the join has been performed, removing the stadiums with no activity. Once this predicate is moved to the appropriate ON clause it will filter the gamestat's before the join instead of after.

You have experienced the good fortune to encounter this important quirk of SQL, that the positioning of predicates affects the result-set, early in your education.

Comment: Thank you Pieter, you're a life saver. This has been driving me insane for a week. I had some advice from a fellow student much to the same affect as what you were saying but he told me to place it in the wrong spot and that caused faults.